# Any option to filter jquery data like .any() in linq

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a situation where I have to check if a value exist in Jquery ajax call resulted data. I am doing a for each loop to check if id value exist in result data. Do we have any other best option to check this instead of looping. I like .any in linq which checks at one shot. Any alternate idea in jquery?

```
 var id=10;
 success: function (result) {

                    var found = false;
                    $.each(result.value, function (i, item) {
                        if (item.Group_Id == Id) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!found) {
                        alert('Not Found');
                    }
```

Comment: Without searching, i'd say there is no method like that, but what's wrong with that code?

Comment: Just FYI, [linq's `any` function has a loop under the hood](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq/blob/master/linq.js#L1127). While it makes your code look nicer because it hides the loop, it doesn't magically get it more efficiently without a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that the background work would be the same even in Linq with your comments. On the other side I am looking for a much cleaner code. Any suggestions please.

Comment: IMO, this code is clean (but could be optimised) but you could build you own prototype function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function that should match your request.

Consider that even `any()` really enumerates all elements because there's an intrinsic minimal complexity to these algorithms that cannot be avoided. An alternative to a full enumeration are hash sets with buckets (much like ISAM indices) but that's a completely different story because then you have to pre-compute the index itself.

So, really, whatever you use (each or filter and practically all **LinQ to Collection** methods) really has the same complexity under the hood.

I want to thank [Karl-André Gagnon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324107/karl-andr%c3%a9-gagnon) for his useful comment about using **grep**, instead. Read below for a link to the page he proposes. I agree with both, him and ajp15243.

Comment: Filter is for DOM element. What you really want to use is [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

Comment: It would appear that `filter` works on a jQuery-wrapped array of arbitrary objects, even though the `.foo()` methods of jQuery are meant to be called on jQuery object lists of DOM elements. I suppose it isn't that surprising, but I'm not sure how much one should rely on that behavior given the *intended* use case. Ex: `arr=[{a:1},{a:2},{b:'foo'}]; $(arr).filter(function(){return this.a;});`